# How to access Azure ID Token in an Azure Web App

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, streamlit

I have an Azure Web App built in python that I have configured the Microsoft authentication so users first have to login to our companies Microsoft AD. Reading through the documentation after this process happens the users id_token is stored in the Token Library that can be accessed at /.auth/me which exists on a different server from the web app. I want my web app to be able to access this token I try sending a get request to /.auth/me but the AppServiceAppAuth cookie is needed and I cant seem to pull that from my session

Am I going about this completely wrong?

If it is not clear the app is built on the python streamlit library

I try this:

```
@st.cache_resource
def get_manager():
    return CookieManager()

cookie_manager = CookieManager()

st.subheader("All Cookies:")
cookies = cookie_manager.get_all()
st.write(cookies)
```

And it displays some of the cookies but not the AppServiceAppAuth cookie even though when I pull up the web developer tools and look at the stored cookies it is present

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below streamlit code to get the Azure Active Directory ID token from the Azure web app.

**Code :**

```py
import streamlit as st
import msal

authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>"
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
client_id = "<client_ID>"
client_secret = "<client_secret>"
redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8501/callback"  

msal_app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret,
)

st.title("MSAL Streamlit Example")

def get_id_token():
    auth_url = msal_app.get_authorization_request_url(
        scope,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    )
    st.write(f"Click [here]({auth_url}) to login and obtain the ID token.")

if st.button("Get ID Token"):
    get_id_token()

def display_id_token(id_token):
    st.success(f"ID Token: {id_token}")

query_params = st.experimental_get_query_params()
if "code" in query_params:
    code = query_params["code"]
    token_response = msal_app.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
        code,
        scopes=scope,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    )
    id_token = token_response.get("id_token")
    if id_token:
        display_id_token(id_token)
    else:
        st.error("Error obtaining ID token. Please try again.")
```

I added the below URL'S in the Azure AD App Redirect URI as below,

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

I followed below to get the ID token from the Azure AD in local.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then, I deployed this to Azure web app and checked the output in the web app at browser as below.

[image]